# php interface method overriding

Tags: php, interface, overriding

```
<?php
interface a {
    public function bar();
}
interface b extends a {
    public function foo();
    public function bar($a);
}

?>
```

It is showing a fatal error of signature missmatch in method. is not it possible to override a method of interface in php?

Comment: It's possible if it has the same signature. Your `b.bar` accepts `$a`, while `a.bar` does not, which is the source of the fatal error.

Comment: @Yoshi what is the point if it has the same signature. What is the point altogether.

Comment: @Esailija That's a thing you'll have to ask the php devs. I just pointed out the error, that tripped me often enough myself ;)

Comment: @Esailija You are still able to implement the same function in another way. You may also emulate overloading using [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func-get-args)

Comment: @yoshi i know the reason of the error. i want to know if it is possible or not in this way or any other way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the signature mismatch error because the two `bar` functions aren't compatible.

You can fix it by changing the interface to

```
interface b extends a {
    public function foo();
    public function bar($a = null);
}
```

Although this might not be a complete solution, as you will now get a `Can't inherit abstract function` error.

Comment: The `Can't inherit...` error is [a php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43200), fixed in 5.3.9.